# « Nous facturons un mois à l'avance » ou « Nous facturons un mois d'avance » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, commerce

Je sais qu'il n'y a pas une grande différence, mais je me demande toujours quelle est la bonne façon d'expliquer à un client comment nous facturons. Est-ce-que « Nous facturons un mois à l'avance » ou « Nous facturons un mois d'avance » ou les deux sont correctes ?

Aussi, pour expliquer les frais au prorata, avez-vous l'habitude de dire « les frais sur votre facture est calculée au prorata » ? Ce qui veut dire que le client n'est pas entièrement facturé pour les services, car il a commencé à les utiliser dans le milieu de son cycle de facturation.

Comment: Dans ce contexte, on ajoutera "temporis" :  *les frais sur votre facture sont calculés au prorata temporis*.

Comment: @Graffito partielle marche aussi?

Comment: L'utilisation de "partiel" conduirait à une expressionn assez imprécise. "un calcul au prorata temporis" est une bonne formulation.

Comment: Pour la première phrase, on peut dire "nous facturons mensuellement à terme à échoir" (ce qui signifie facturation par avance). On dirait , "... à terme échu" pour indiquer que l'on facture une fois la prestation effectuée.

Answer (score 5):

Il y a un différence.

> Nous facturons un mois à l'avance

Cela signifie généralement que le client paye un mois avant le début de son contrat

> Nous facturons un mois d'avance

Cela signifie que le client va payer le mois en cours + le mois suivant

Vous pouvez aussi dire :

> Nous facturons chaque mois à l'avance

Cela signifie donc que pour payer le mois de Février, on va être facturé fin Janvier ou début Février.

Pour la seconde phrase, je dirait tout simplement:

> Votre facture est calculée au prorata

Answer (score 2):

En fait, il y a une grande différence entre les deux.

Nous facturons un mois à l'avance veut dire que la facture est envoyée ou présentée  un mois avant le début du travail ou des travaux à effectuer ou d'une marchandise à livrer, bref, on parle d'une facture pour un service attendu à une certaine date. L'important dans ce cas est la date et seulement la date.

Nous facturons un mois d'avance fait référence à l'objet de la facture, c'est-à-dire quelque chose qui se paye au mois, comme un loyer par exemple.

«Pour ne pas oublier de payer mon loyer, je donne à mon propriétaire deux mois d'avance.»

«Pour être à l'heure malgré la tempête de neige, je pars une heure à l'avance».

Mais:

«Parce que j'ai gagné la dernière manche, j'ai trois points d'avance sur mon adversaire.

«D'avance» et «À l'avance» ne veulent pas dire la même chose.

Answer (score 1):

> Nous facturons un mois à l'avance

signifie que la facturation est effectuée chaque mois.
alors que :

> Nous facturons un mois d'avance

peut signifier une facturation pour un mois unique.

Pour la deuxième phrase, je dirais plutôt :

> les frais sur votre facture **sont calculés** au prorata